# Will a win32diskimager copy of my R-Pi2 work on my R-Pi3?

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, backup

I used Win32diskimager to make a backup of my raspberry pi 2 sd card. I had upgraded to a R-Pi3 and it just occurred to me that it might not work. So I figured I'd at least give it a try and it didn't. I figured that makes sense but just want to make sure that this isn't because some other issue (like that the backup file had no extension when I wrote it to the new sd card - no idea why Win32 saved it like that). Thanks for any and all info! Have a good one!

Comment: I use the same card in a 2 and a 3 so there's no reason it should not work *unless*, as thlngan points out, the image hasn't been kept up to date.

Comment: "it didn't" is not particularly informative. If you gave a better description of what it IS doing you may get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things to consider here:

- how old was the install on your RPi2? Versions of OS's that predate the release of the RPi3 will definitely not work.
- is your backup actually good? Try it in your RPi2. If it doesn't boot, either your backup or the SD card it was burned to are defective.
- is your RPi3 in working order? The increased power requirements for the RPi3 mean they need a more powerful AC adapter than previous iterations of the Pi. Do you have adequate power?